# Connecting to BACnet device giving single use socket address error

Tags: python, windows, bacnet

I've tried to look through posts to see if i could find anything but haven't managed to find it yet.

I'm running the SCADA BACnet device simulator on my localhost.I'm assuming the ip for the device is my localhost ip since the only IP i could find was in the `deviceAddressBinding` property which showed `192.168.x.xx`

I am running through the bacpypes(python library for bacnet) tutorial for the `SampleApplication` and when I first tried running the tutorial, it stated that my `.ini file ip is not a valid address in the context`. So I tried to put in the simulator's settings to try and connect to the simulator and now it's giving me a `Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted` error. Not quite sure where to go from here, am I perhaps missing something?

my .ini file:

```
[BACpypes]
objectName: Testing Device
address: 192.168.x.xx #tutorial came with 128.253.109.40/20
objectIdentifier: 123
maxApduLengthAccepted: 1024
segmentationSupported: segmentedBoth
vendorIdentifier: 123
foreignPort: 47808
foreignBBMD: 192.168.1.254
foreignTTL: 30
```

My simulator properties:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be a windows issue. Replaced :

```
this_application = WhoIsIAmApplication(this_device, args.ini.address)
```

with:

```
this_application = WhoIsIAmApplication(this_device, ('', 47808))
```

Answer (score 0):

your sample application and BACnet simulators are opening a server socket. looks like both are using the same port number. you can change the port number in ini file as given below

address: 192.168.1.22:47809

by default the BACPypes sample applications run on the 47808 port number unless you explicitly mention in the configuration file.